# How to unsubscribe one Google group from another Google group mailing list

Tags: google-groups

How to unsubscribe one Google group from another Google group mailing list?

- I am a member of foo@googlegroups.com
- foo@googlegroups.com is a member of bar@googlegroups.com

How can I unsubscribe foo@ from the bar@ email list?

Comment: Are you the administrator of these groups?

Comment: lol, well I asked this question over 4 years ago, so I have no idea which groups I was referring to! I assume that I was not an admin for `bar@` otherwise unsubscribing would be easy. I may or may not have been an admin for `foo@`. Does that affect the answer?

Comment: Yes, that affects the answer. Are you still facing this problem? Does the current answer was/is helpful to you? At the current question state, it might be automatically deleted in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I was able to do this just now by

1. giving my own email account a different "send email as" address (as per [these instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en))
2. setting that address as my default
3. sending an email to bar+unsubscribe@googlegroups.com

Note: you need to actually be receiving emails from the `foo` group, so that you can receive the verification code that you will need to tell google you are allowed to send emails from the `foo` group's address.